# Hosting WCF Service in Oracle Weblogic Server

Tags: wcf, weblogic, weblogic12c

Our team has developed a number of WCF services in Visual Studio. Currently we are hosting them on IIS server. However, a need occured to host them on Oracle WebLogic Server 12c. Is this possible? Are there any pitfalls associated with that approach?

Comment: using a proxy java web service is a viable options ? I doubt you can publish some .NET stuff on a java server. You may also resort to some kind of ESB (Aqualogic anyone ?)

Comment: proxy java service is not an option - it is required to host services on specific server (which runs on linux using mentioned Oracle WebLogic Server)

Comment: I think you'll have to rewrite the services in java, AFAIK there's no way to host .NET code on a J2EE server. The proxy/bus solution indeed requires the presence of both Weblogic and IIS but would save you from rewriting all stuffs.

Comment: And if we decided to go with proxy solution - would it be just a simple java service consuming wcf services hosted on iis and exposing their interfaces? (a kind of facade grouping all interfaces)?.

Comment: yes, a simple consumer of your WCF service exposed as a Web Service itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. After some further research and your insight, a proxy seems like the most sane solution.